# Decoding access_token in Hangfire's IDashboardAuthorizationFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, jwt, hangfire, webapi2

I've used [this](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) and [that](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) link to secure my WebApi2 with tokens. When i authenticate it responds with something like this:

```
{
    ".expires": "Wed, 30 Jan 2019 14:14:44 GMT",
    ".issued": "Wed, 30 Jan 2019 13:44:44 GMT",
    "access_token": "ZYQm9txvb_fVqYo8Be-NQzC1o3DQM3HYwIdi_2aDNazXW3x9BlYwXqGLBf_Ptqv3azR6uSzhp3_CIjPGGDuolmC0Z1PaHOZJKHn7DJHVnJlMN4FYlE_oCAA1HgM1sWYY97-a21gUNsGLdVCA1UNVo_u2E52ef-sl9-2aOTMJcrJli--waNBBKVok5aP_H4ufdAdxkGTGYrvdTU9Tm2zduadsGeeifI522QY8EwwDNQ2T-6A9_yBuI0yRT-B-TzayUevKvITkZZBKbMAMJNDNQC_dvqiZeaVlKiaxLZsnZ6V1t49nEDQ58pXmDqfdWIF88sbcQXFR_zt5Rly7znL8bWCY1OEuLcF_wH-NHnuyd7PCTT0cxUNu75Vz0wlM5SidxqoJ1KBi2I64IqPvXEObf5NXJb9QP3ZKOGWKtHqaanj9dOS2URGfY8VxfQDpkaMc",
    "as:client_id": "5F6617AD-3364-41EB-B0F1-F538C950FA09",
    "expires_in": 1799,
    "refresh_token": "4d7e77c8c0cf4cc2bc417a6166c07d4d,
    "token_type: "bearer"
}
```

When i invoke authorized api methods i need to attach `access_token` as `Bearer` token to my requests - so it works as expected. Now i want to use this token to also authorize access to Hangfire's dashboard. After acquiring token from server i save it in a cookie as `token_cookie`. Then on server side i try to read it like this:

```
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter : IDashboardAuthorizationFilter
{
    public bool Authorize(DashboardContext context)
    {
        var cookies = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies;

        if (cookies["token_cookie"] != null)
        {
            var jwtCookie = cookies["token_cookie"];
            var jwtToken = jwtCookie.Value;
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = handler.ReadToken(jwtToken);
            // check if user is in admin role etc.
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Access token has the same value as on the client. Yet, ReadToken method throws error:

> IDX12741: JWT: '[PII is hidden]' must have three segments (JWS) or
>   five segments (JWE).

How can I read this token to access user claims? Since `Authorize` attribute works on my controllers it would seem that the jwt middleware can somehow read it. Am I missing something?

My auth configuration looks like this:

```
private static void AddJwtAuthentication(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = false,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
        RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider(),
    };

    // Token Generation
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
}
```

Comment: an OAuth bearer token is not the same as a JWT and is also not designed to be decoded by yourself.

Comment: So what are You saying - i can't secure HF dashboard with OAuth bearer tokens?

Comment: I'm not familiar with hangfire. I just see that you create an OAuth bearer token, which you have shown above and then try to interpret it as a JWT (which - not surprisingly - fails). You either need to create a JWT for your WebApi2 (the same author has some nice tutorials about JWT too) or implement OAuth bearer tokens for hangfire, if possible.

Comment: I've used JWT implementation - now it works. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome :)